# How to apply css style to one div when another div has certain text

Tags: jquery, css, each

I have the following HTML, and need to apply a css background to the title div `.well-sm` when the "type" in "overlays" is "teaser". It is currently applying the color to the entire overlays section. How can I apply the color to the title div?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href = "/video/4060?region=US">
      <figure class = "media">
        <img src = "" height="300"/>
      </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p class="lead well well-sm"><a href="">Title of Post</a></p>
    <p class="lead text-uppercase"></p>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><dt>ID:4060</dt></div>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <dt>Description:</dt><dd class="description">Description of post</dd>
          <dt>Date Created:</dt><dd>2014-12-09T16:32:00Z</dd>
          <dt>Date Published</dt><dd></dd>
          <dt>Location:</dt><dd>Dec 9</dd>
          <dt>Duration:</dt><dd>5.6653333 seconds</dd>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <dt>Overlay:</dt>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <dl class="list-unstyled">
                          <li><strong><i>Type:</i></strong> TEASER</li>
                          <li><strong><i>Title:</i></strong> Title of Post</li>
                          <li><strong><i>Byline:</i></strong> </li>
                          <li><strong><i>Section:</i></strong> Top News</li>
                          <li><strong><i>Entity:</i></strong> TimelineDescriptorOverlay</li>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".list-unstyled").each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    var color;
    var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();

    if (content.indexOf("teaser")) {
        color = "#ff9100";
    }

    if (color) {
            $el.closest('div')
            .find('li')
            .css("background", color);
        }
    });
```

SEE JSFIDDLE DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/yeco6rkh/)

Comment: What do you mean by *"the title div"*..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are targeting the over lay section.  You need to target the title div.

```
        $('.well-sm').css("background",color);//entire div
        $('.well-sm').find('a').css("background",color);//just the word
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeco6rkh/10/)

Comment: This is close, but I need to apply it only to the titles that have "TEASER" as the "Type:" under the div "list-unstyled".

Comment: Place the code in your if statement.  I updated the fiddle to show that.

Comment: That still only sets the background color of the title to orange, no matter what the value of the "type" is in the "overlays" section of the HTML.

Comment: Your if statement needs to make sure the indexOf is not returning -1.  Currently your if statement returns true even though it's not finding "teaser".  http://jsfiddle.net/yeco6rkh/6/

Comment: That still affects all the title divs, because it's not focused on just the "list-unstyled" sections that have type: teaser. If you change the indexOf("teaser") to something else, it still applies the title color to all titles.

Comment: You can travel up the DOM using parents() and then find the closest  title.  

`$('.list-unstyled').parents('.col-xs-6').find('.well-sm').css("background", color);`

Comment: This doesn't solve the logic of testing the content of "type" to ensure it is "Teaser". This is merely applying the background color to the title div. So the idea is that ONLY if the type is "type: teaser" should the title have a background color.

Comment: So how do I target only the overlays that have "Type: teaser", then apply that style to the title?

Comment: Use the contains() selector as another answer on this thread did and you can travel up the DOM from there.

`$(".list-unstyled li:contains('TEASER')").parents('.col-xs-6').find('.well-sm').css("background",'#ff9100');`

Comment: The contains() has to be an exact match (case sensitive).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeco6rkh/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/yeco6rkh/3/

```
var div = $el.closest('div');
        div.find("li").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().indexOf("Title") > -1;            
        }).css("background", color);
```

Comment: Here's a better example. Only the "Teasers" one should have a highlighted title: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/yeco6rkh/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```js
$(".list-unstyled").each(function() {

  var $el = $(this);
  var color;
  var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();

  if (content.indexOf("teaser")) {
    color = "#ff9100";
  }

  if (color) {
    $el.closest('div')
      .find('li')
      .css("background", color);
  }
});

$(".list-unstyled li:contains('TEASER')").css("background", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="/video/4060?region=US">
      <figure class="media">
        <img src="" height="300" />
      </figure>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <p class="lead well well-sm"><a href="">Title of Post</a>
    </p>
    <p class="lead text-uppercase"></p>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><dt>ID:4060</dt>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"> <dt>Description:</dt>
          <dd class="description">Description of post</dd> <dt>Date Created:</dt>
          <dd>2014-12-09T16:32:00Z</dd> <dt>Date Published</dt>
          <dd></dd> <dt>Location:</dt>
          <dd>Dec 9</dd> <dt>Duration:</dt>
          <dd>5.6653333 seconds</dd>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"> <dt>Overlay:</dt>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <dl class="list-unstyled">
                <li><strong><i>Type:</i></strong> TEASER</li>
                <li><strong><i>Title:</i></strong> Title of Post</li>
                <li><strong><i>Byline:</i></strong> 
                </li>
                <li><strong><i>Section:</i></strong> Top News</li>
                <li><strong><i>Entity:</i></strong> TimelineDescriptorOverlay</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at jQuery but you could try this

```js
$(".list-unstyled").each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();

    if (content.indexOf("teaser")) {
       $('.well-sm').addClass('color');
    }

});
```

CSS:

```
.color{background-color:#ff9100;}
```